# Storing a readonly ref to a struct in an instance field

Tags: c#, memory-management, reference

With C# 7.2 you can pass structs via an `in` parameter, which is basically a `readonly ref`.

```
class Model {
    private readonly TStruct _s;

    Model(in TStruct s) {
        _s = s;
    }
}
```

**In the code above, where `TStruct` is a `struct`, am I assigning the reference to `_s` or do I copy the whole struct?** What I want is to avoid unnecessary memory copying. As I only need to read data from `s` I'd think a `readonly ref` would do it. Unfortunately, I can't mark `_s` as a `readonly ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With C# 7.2 you can pass structs via an in parameter, which is basically a readonly ref.

Yes, and it is EXPLICIT.

> In the code above, where TStruct is a struct, am I assigning the reference to _s or do I 
>   copy the whole struct?

Copy whole struct the moment you assign it ti _s. You avoid one more copy possibly (implementation detail) calling the constructor because THERE only a pointer is passed in, but that may be optimized out by the JIT.

> In the code above, where TStruct is a struct, am I assigning the reference to _s or do 
>   I copy the whole struct?

Then do not use a struct. Generally, pointers can only be used along function calls or temporary variables - _s is none of those. They are there to avoid copying structs around during operations, NOT to change the storage model.

Comment: I would go further to say a `class` is exactly what is being requested - a data store that is normally referenced and not copied.

Comment: Can not be said from the little infromation given and is not asked. THere are strong indications for this, but it may well be a malformed/minimalistic question.

Comment: In my specific scenario I read marshalled binary data into a struct and want to use it with minimal performance footprint. Seems like I have to construct a class from struct data right after read.

Comment: Depends - if the data survives longer, yes. Really depends on the API.